# Checking if user entered anything?

Tags: java

I am trying to check if a user entered a number and if not, then it uses a default number like 10. How do i check if the user just presses enter and doesn't enter anything in Java

```
input = scanner.nextInt();
pseudo code:
if(input == user just presses enter without entering anything){
    input = 10;
}
else just proceed with input = what user entered
```

Comment: Ok, are using Scanner to take in the input or what? Show us the code where the user inputs their data

Comment: yes scanner, like number = input.scanner();

Comment: Ok, post your code that does this, I can definitely help you with this

Answer (score 2):

```
//scanner is a Scanner
int i; // declare it before the block
try {
  i = scanner.nextInt();
}
catch (InputMismatchException ime) {
  i = 10;
}
// i is some integer from the user, or 10
```

Comment: Also need to check for `NoSuchElementException` which is thrown if the user ends the TTY session; so, `InputMismatchException | NoSuchElementException ime` on Java7 or a whole new catch block on anything less.

Comment: I don't want an exception, i want i = 10 if nothing is entered, so what do i do

Comment: @RichardBarley This is **exactly** what the answer is doing for you. Please read up on `try...catch` blocks.

Comment: @RichardBarley That's what this will do. If it's a number, it gets the number. If an exception is thrown, we catch it, set i=10, and go on with the rest of the program

Comment: However, a more elegant solution that doesn't involve the expensive stack-unwinding of the exception mechanism is to use `hasNextInt()`. You'd still want a catch block for `NoSuchElementException`, though.

Comment: @Qix look at the underlying code for hasNextInt. :) http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/7u40-b43/java/util/Scanner.java#Scanner.hasNextInt%28%29

Comment: @JonKiparsky True; that's implementation specific though. Absolutely no guarantee that's how the Oracle JRE does things, nor is it any guarantee any other implementation of Java does things.

Comment: @Qix - true enough, but since it is the reference implementation, I figure it's probably a pretty good indication. In any case, we're dealing with user input - the slow point here is not going to be unwinding the stack. If this were being used to check input from a file, I'd say go with a regex, but in this case that's completely unnecessary

Comment: still waits for something to be entered after i press enter

Comment: Not on my machine it doesn't, but the comments section isn't a great place to compare code.

Answer (score 2):

First things first, geeeeeez guys, when the OP says something like

"I don't want an exception, i want i = 10 if nothing is entered, so what do i do"

That should clue you in that he probably doesn't know too much about exceptions (maybe even java) and might need a simple answer. And if that's not possible, explain to him the difficult ones.

Alright, here's the plain and simple way to do it

```
String check;

int input = 10;

check = scanner.nextLine/*Int*/();

if(check.equals(""))
{

    //do nothing since input already equals 10

}

else
{

    input = Integer.parseInt(check);

}
```

Let me explain what this code is doing. You were originally using nextInt() to get your number for input, correct? The problem is, nextInt() only responds if the user actually inputs something, not if they press enter. In order to check for enter, we used a method that actually responds when the user presses enter and used that to ensure that our code does what we wanted to. One thing I recommend using is an API, Java has one.

Here's the link for the API [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/)

And here's the link for the actual method I used [HERE](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine()). You can find descriptions and instructions on many methods you'll run into on this API.

Now, back to my answer, that's the easy way to do it. Problem is, this code isn't necessarily safe. It'll throw exceptions if something goes wrong, or if someone is trying to hack into your system. For example, if you were to enter a letter instead of pressing enter or entering a number, it would throw an exception. What you've been seeing in the other answers is what we call exception handling, that's how we make sure exceptions don't happen. If you want an answer that'll catch most of these exceptions, you need to make sure your code catches them, or avoids them all together (I'm simplifying things immensely). The above answer is working code, but isn't safe code, you wouldn't ever use something like this all by itself in real life.

Here is something that might be considered safe code. And no exceptions to keep it simple! ;)

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SOQ15
{

   public Scanner scanner;

   public SOQ15()
   {

      scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

      int input = 10;

      boolean isAnInt = true;

      String check;

      check = scanner.nextLine/*Int*/();

      if(check.equals(""))
      {

         //do nothing since input already equals 10

      }


      for(int i = 0; i < check.length(); i++)
      {

         if(check.charAt(i) >= '0' && check.charAt(i) <= '9' && check.length() < 9)
         {

         //This is if a number was entered and the user didn't just press enter

         }

         else
         {

            isAnInt = false;

         }



      }

      if(isAnInt)
      {

         input = Integer.parseInt(check);
         System.out.println("Here's the number - " + input);

      }

   }

   public static void main(String[] args)
   {


      SOQ15 soq = new SOQ15();


   }

}
```

I don't have time to go into all the details right now, but ask and I'll gladly respond when I get the time! :)

Answer (score 0):

Well if you are using scanner, given the details provided, you can try:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
if in.hasNextInt(){ //Without this, the next line would throw an input mismatch exception if given a non-integer
     int i = in.nextInt(); //Takes in the next integer
}
```

You said you wanted a default of 10 otherwise so:

```
else {
     int i = 10;
}
```

Comment: Missing semi-colons, if statement is syntactically incorrect, doesn't check for end of stream. This code would never compiler under a normal compiler.

Comment: Sorry, have not written java in almost a year, too used to python :)

Comment: Also, it doesn't deal with the user's original concern, which was setting a default value. Thanks for trying, but no.